# Оптимизация приложения с учетом GO-специфики

Tags: golang

Есть небольшое приложения для генерации псевдо-логов. По условиям ТЗ лог-файлы создаются каждый час с именем вида `app_d-m-Y_H:i.log`

Я решил эту задачу "в лоб" :

```
 func main() {
    var err error
    var i int

    t := time.Now()
    time_layout := fmt.Sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d_%02d_%02d", t.Day(), t.Month(), t.Year(), t.Hour(), t.Minute())
    log_file := fmt.Sprintf(cfgvars.LogFile, time_layout)

    /* связываем вывод log-сообщений с файлом */
    logTo := os.Stderr
    if logTo, err = os.OpenFile(log_file, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer logTo.Close()
    log.SetOutput(logTo)

    c := 0
    for {
            i++
            if c == 1202 {
                    t = time.Now()
                    time_layout = fmt.Sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d_%02d_%02d", t.Day(), t.Month(), t.Year(), t.Hour(), t.Minute())
                    log_file = fmt.Sprintf(cfgvars.LogFile, time_layout)

                    /* связываем вывод log-сообщений с файлом */
                    logTo = os.Stderr
                    if logTo, err = os.OpenFile(log_file, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600); err != nil {
                            log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    defer logTo.Close()
                    log.SetOutput(logTo)
                    c = 0
            }
            log.Printf("%s %s[%d]:\t%d\t%s\n", "host", os.Args[0], os.Getpid(), i, "some message")
            time.Sleep(999 * time.Millisecond)
            c++
    }
}
```

Можно все-это привести к более изящному виду? Может с использованием каналов и прочего великолепия?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если код рабочий, то лучше задайте вопрос на [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @GreenDragon: рабочий. Попробую. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Если линукс то можно использовать cron для запуска функции с параметром каждый час, чем отправлять ее постоянно спать, тем более неясно все это или нет =)